# Not receiveing Datagram with PYQT5 Multicast UDP

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp, multicast, pyqt5

I have the following Code Snippets and run both in the same VirtualBox VM. I get no error, yet I receive nothing. In wireshark, I see packets coming from my local Adress to the multicast address, but none returning.

receiver.py

```
import PyQt5.QtNetwork as QTN

groupaddr = QTN.QHostAddress("239.255.43.22") 
udp = QTN.QUdpSocket()
udp.setSocketOption(QTN.QAbstractSocket.MulticastLoopbackOption,1)
udp.setSocketOption(QTN.QAbstractSocket.MulticastTtlOption,32)
udp.bind(QTN.QHostAddress.AnyIPv4,54555,QTN.QUdpSocket.ShareAddress)
ni = QTN.QNetworkInterface()
udp.joinMulticastGroup(groupaddr,ni)


while True:
    if udp.isReadable():
        data,host,port = udp.readDatagram(udp.pendingDatagramSize())
        print(data)
        print(host)
        udp.leaveMulticastGroup(groupaddr)
        udp.close()
        break
```

sender.py

```
import PyQt5.QtNetwork as QTN


groupaddr = QTN.QHostAddress("239.255.43.22")
udp = QTN.QUdpSocket()
udp.setSocketOption(QTN.QAbstractSocket.MulticastLoopbackOption,1)
udp.setSocketOption(QTN.QAbstractSocket.MulticastTtlOption,32)
ni = QTN.QNetworkInterface()

udp.bind(QTN.QHostAddress.AnyIPv4,54555,QTN.QUdpSocket.ShareAddress)
udp.setMulticastInterface(ni)
udp.joinMulticastGroup(groupaddr,ni)

udp.writeDatagram("test",groupaddr,54555)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am an idiot and should have RTFM more careful, using hasPendingDatagrams() instead of isReadable() solved it